# WordPress: Google-loaded jQuery doesn't work in wp-admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using jQuery in my theme, loading it from Google's CDN network, and calling it like this in my functions.php file:

```
function bb_google_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', false, '1.4.4');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

if(!is_admin()){
    add_action('init', 'bb_google_jquery');
}
```

The problem is, even if it's wrapped in the conditional tag, it stops wp-admin jQuery stuff, such as the sidebar menu dropdowns, and dashboard dropdowns from working. Removing the `is_admin` makes it work correctly.

However, I need it to be wrapped in the conditional tag because otherwise I can't move menu items around.

Anything I'm doing wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you more clearly describe what you're trying to accomplish?  Do you want this drag-drop functionality for both admin and non-admin or just one?  If just one, please clearly state which one.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this functionality as an admin, but your conditional says to load it only if the session is not an admin session.  Perhaps removing the ! would help?

```
 if( is_admin() ) {
```

The way it's setup in your code says "load JQuery for all non-admins only."

Comment: Yes, that what I mentioned - if I remove the conditional tag (ie. the if is_admin) and allow it to load in the admin area, it will stop other jQuerty stuff (namely moving menu items around) from working. Vicious circle right here!

Comment: @Justine - Did you mean to load JQuery (drag drop) for admins, non-admins, or just one?  I am now confused.

Comment: Let me try explaining it better: 1) conditional tag (if is_admin) on: dropdowns in the WP admin dashboard not working; 2) conditional tag off: menu items can't be dragged in Appearance/Menus - both having and not having that conditional tag `if( is_admin() )` causes a problem.

Comment: @Justine - I don't think you understand.  You just pasted if ( is_admin ) in this comment, but in your question you put if ( !is_admin() ).  Are you trying to activate JQuery for admin users or for non-admin users?  Can you please clarify that you understand that ! means NOT?  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but I think you really need to edit your post and really break this down for us. :)  Can you put echo is_admin() in your PHP code to see what the value of is_admin is?  Can you verify that JQuery is or isn't loading when things are in their broken state by checking browser source/debugger?

Comment: Yes, my bad, I just copy pasted your code, cause I was too lazy to tab to my code editor and forgot to add the !. Yes I understand ! means not :) I have if( !is_admin() ) in my code. Otherwise it works like I mentioned - having this condition causes one problem, removing it (or removing the !) causes another problem.

Comment: Very wierd.  It sounds like maybe there could be a conflict somewhere.  Are extra libraries being loaded when you leave that out vs put it in, like maybe no JQuery is loaded or maybe 2 copies of the Jquery is loaded in your browser source?  Do you see any errors in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

**This should work , I guess**

```
function bb_google_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', false, '1.4.4');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

if(is_admin()){
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'bb_google_jquery');
}
```

Better include your js file only on the page where you need it

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'edit.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url('/myscript.js', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

check the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: Please don't 'guess'. If you aren't sure, don't post an answer.